# Error While Creating Header Files in C++

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

There is one header a file Rectangle.hxx

```
#ifndef Rectangle_included
#define Rectangle_included
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "GetL.hxx"
using namespace std;

class Rectangle: public GetL
{
int width;
int value;
public:
Rectangle();
Rectangle(int v, int w);
Rectangle(const Rectangle& b);
int getWidth();
int getValue();
Rectangle & plus(int newval);
};
#endif //Rectangle_included
```

The file GetL.hxx is defined like this:

```
#ifndef GetL_included
#define GetL_included
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class GetL
{
public:
virtual int getWidth();
};
#endif //GetL_include
```

The file Rectangle.cxx contains various definitions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Rectangle.hxx"
using namespace std;

Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
 value=0;
 width=0;
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(int v, int w)
{
 value=v;
 width=w;
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle& b)
{
 value= b.value;
 width= b.width;
}
int Rectangle::getWidth()
{
 return width;
}
int Rectangle::getValue()
{
  return value;
}
Rectangle& Rectangle::plus(int newval)
{
  value+=newval;
  if(value>=pow(2,width))
cout<<"Overflow";
  return *this;
}
```

But i am getting the error on compiling **Rectangle.cxx**.

```
/tmp/cclETn3R.o:Rectangle.cxx:(.text$_ZN4GetLC2Ev[GetL::GetL()]+0*8): undefined reference to 'vtable for Getl'
```

How can i remove it? How can i define file **GetL.cxx** or i don't need to?

Comment: Please tell us the command you use to build your program, the command which results in the error message you posted.

Comment: Also, have you written GetL.cxx? If so, please show us. Also, you have no `int main()`.

Comment: @Rob i am working in cygwin and used the command `g++ Rectangle.cxx` and i have not wriiten GetL.cxx and main() till now.

Comment: @Rob i have asked about GetL.cxx in second part of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile the different files without linking first. On UNIX compilers this is typically done using the `-c` option. When building the executable you then specify all the produced `.o` objects. Alternatively you can specify all source files at once but this is really only viable for very small projects.

Comment: can u tell me how to do this? i am using cygwin on windows

Comment: Just use `g++ -c Rectangle.cxx` and likewise for other source files. Eventually, put all the files together: `g++ -o program.exe Rectangle.o GetL.o main.o` (I'm not if gcc produces `.o` files or `.obj` when using cygwin: this may need to be changed). To make this less painful you should read up on `make` (or `gmake`) and use a `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `GetL::getWidth()`. Given your other files, you will probably implement it in `GetL.cxx`.

Comment: But i have implemented this function in Rectangle.cxx.

Comment: I see `Rectangle::getWidth` in Rectangle.cxx, but I don't see `GetL::getWidth`. You must also implement `GetL::getWidth`.